# quickest way to calculate powers of 2x2 matrix

Tags: algorithm, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I have a 2x2 matrix `M` which is in general complex. What is the quickest way to multiply `M` by itself `n` times, i.e. M^n? I can think of two ways:

A. diagonalize it and multiply them

B. Break up `n` into groups. For instance, if `n=15`, then I can do the following:

1. A=M*M
2. B=A*A=M^4
3. C=B*B=A^8
4. M*A*B*C=M^15

So in total I need to do 6 matrix multiplications.

My questions are:

1. Which method is faster?
2. Are there any other methods to accomplish this?
3. For my second method, how to implement the algorithm for any `n`? It is easy if `n` is a power of 2, but when it isn't how to break up the multiplication and grouping like in my example given?

Comment: As regards A. you might be unlucky and the matrix may not be diagonalisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think A is better since in A, after you diagonalize the matrix it's O(1), while in B the complexity is O(log(n))

2.Beside the trivial one (multiply the matrix by itself n times), I don't know of any.

3. You should represent the n as binary number, and multiply just the places of "1". for example: 15=1111 (bin) so you have: 2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3, and thus you need to multiply all the above to get the answer. let's take another n, say n=23. 
   The binary representation is 10111, so you need the powers until 5 (2^0,2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4) - and you take just the places of "1" - so you multiply the 2^0*2^1*2^2*2^4 (because the 4-th index, referring to 2^3 is 0 you don't multiply it).